# Twitter Developer site don't allow me to add Privacy and Terms URLs

Tags: ios, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-fabric

In my iOS App, I have integrated Twitter login successfully and now I need to have access to ser's email address. For that it is required to add Privacy policy and Terms URLs of my iOS App to the Twitter Developer portal.

But, when I add those URLs and try to update settings, it throw an error

> The client application failed validation: url contains malware URL.
>
> The client application failed validation: organization.url contains
>   malware URL.

Even when I try to add App Icon on that site, they give me an error.

What may be the reason ? Also both the URLs are valid and contain full description of my App policies / terms.

See below screenshot for reference.

[image]

Comment: What are those particular URLs? Also, get in touch with the Twitter Developer Support Team.

Comment: Thanks 4K, those URLs are (1) Privacy policy (2) Terms and service. These two URLs are required to enable user email address permission in Twitter Developer site.

Comment: Do you have idea how to contact Twitter Developers Support Team ?

Comment: You can contact them at https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter's support site has a page on [what to do if your links are tagged as unsafe](https://support.twitter.com/articles/90491), and a link where you can file a report.